# Remove Geometry from map using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I need to remove a geometry from the map. It may be a marker, circle, polyline etc. 
I don't see any method like remove, clear or destroy. I already know how to clear everything on the map but this is not what I need.

I would like to remove it with javascript.

Comment: In ArcMap,simply start editing (from editor toolbar) and pressing delete key,deletes any selected feature from different layers.But seems this is not exactly what you want.May you provide more information how you want geometries get removed from map?

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I have a button and on click I want to delete the geometry with javascript.

Comment: And how you select geometry which must get selected?is it included in map selection list?

Comment: I use esri/toolbars/edit and when user clicks on a shape then the toolbar is activated. A global variable is used to "store" the selected geometry.

Comment: In ArcGISDesktop/ArcEdit/ArcMap you can provide an extension for ArcMap which when get registered on Windows,it add a toolbar/button to ArcMap and in OnClick event of that button you can iterate in different layers,find target geometries and use Delete() function in IFeature interface to delete those geometries.I'm not skilled with Java script and I doubt  it is possible to implement ICommand interface using Java script.But sure it's possible in ArcMap to do this using Python without having to write such extension.

Comment: Please post it because i can't : Thanks a lot for your responses. I found the answer. The trick is to know the graphic that coresponds to the geometry. So you olny have to use :

    map.graphics.remove(your_graphic);

Comment: @Reza note that this question is about the [ArcGIS Server JavaScript API](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/) rather than ArcMap

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the Graphic is added directly to the map, you can just call `map.graphics.remove(the_graphic)`, where `the_graphic` is the graphic that you want to remove.

You can also call  `map.graphics.clear();` to remove all graphics added in this way.

If you have added graphics to a particular graphics layer, then you need to remove the graphic from that particular layer, by calling something like `gLayer.remove(the_graphic)` where `gLayer` is your graphic layer and `the_graphic` is the graphic that you want to remove.

For completeness sake, if you want to remove all graphics contained in the map, you can use the following function:

```
    function clearGraphics() {
        //first remove all graphics added directly to map
        map.graphics.clear();

        //now go into each graphic layer and clear it
        var graphicLayerIds = map.graphicsLayerIds;
        var len = graphicLayerIds.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var gLayer = map.getLayer(graphicLayerIds[i]);
            //clear this Layer
            gLayer.clear();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I wanted to remove only one graphic, not the whole map.

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to know the graphic that coresponds to the geometry.

So you only have to use :

```
map.graphics.remove(your_graphic);
```

Comment: You should note that this will not work if the given graphic is added to a particular graphic layer

Comment: I don't use layers. I add them dirrectrly to the map.graphics.

Comment: You might not be doing this right now, but this warning for other people who search for this, and reach this post in the future. The clarification is for them.

Comment: this answer seems almost like a copy/paste of the longer and more thorough answer that @DevdattaTengshe gave. Why not just accept that?

Comment: Because @DevdattaTengshe removes all graphics, I wanted to remove only one graphic.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're working with graphics elements on the map, which were added using the Editor toolbar.

In this case, the graphics are probably located in the map's default [graphicsLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#graphics), or in another graphics layer. See [map.graphicsLayerIds](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#graphicslayerids) for a method to iterate through these layers.

Once you have a pointer to the graphic via its layer, you can then delete it.